# Listening to tab open/close and dealing with existing tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to do something every time a new tab opens up, both via firefox starting and when a new tab is added after firefox starts.  I've been following the example at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser

So I have

```
var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;
container.addEventListener("TabOpen", tabAdded, false);
container.addEventListener("TabClose", tabClosed, false);

function tabAdded(event) {
alert("tabAdded!");
var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
browser.pollingService = new PollingService(createGuid());
browser.pollingService.start();
}
```

And I have a similar function for the close.  This works fine for when tabs are actually opened/closed, but I've run into a couple of problems.

Firstly, when Firefox opens, it has that initial tab already open, but the tabAdded event never fires for it.  Similarly, when I shut down firefox, it never fires the TabClose for those tabs.

It seems like the correct thing to do in this case is to go through all of the tabs that are in the gBrowser.tabContainer and add my service to them as well, and do something similar for when Firefox closes.  Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to hook in to know when Firefox closes (It's also possible there's a much better way to handle this, but I can't think of one).

Secondly, gBrowser.tabContainer can be uninitialized sometimes when my initialization script runs; is there a particular event I should be listening to to know when I can safely add listeners to the tabContainer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a load event listener to give the window time to be ready for you to add your Tab event listeners and create the polling service for the existing tab. Then use an unload event listener to do your cleanup.

Comment: But don't the load/unload events fire every time the web page changes instead of just when things are opening?  How can I differentiate between when the page changes and when firefox is actually opening/closing to know when to do my initializiation/cleanup?

Comment: If you add an ordinary event listener to the (chrome) window then it will only see load and unload events for the chrome window, because they don't bubble up from content windows. (You can still capture them on content windows if you really need them.)

Comment: Ah, that seems to work for opening, but I'm still having trouble on the unload.  I'm hooking up with:   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleTabClosing, false);, but the alert in handleTabClosing is never actually firing; beforeunload is the event I want to be listening to here, right?

Comment: I'm not sure that you're allowed to alert in a beforeunload handler itself. (In a web page you would return a string to request an alert, but I don't know if that works in an extension.) The actual cleanup code would go in an unload handler.

Comment: Ah, excellent, now I'm getting the notifications on both the window opening and the window closing.  Though for some reason the TabOpen events aren't actually firing.  The Tab Close events are firing, but the TabOpen doesn't seem to.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything wrong in your code snippet that would stop it from receiving TabOpen events; I compared it to the example on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser